# Crash when using QuickTime Movie View

Tags: cocoa, quicktime, movie

I am using Xcode to create an Objective-C, cocoa, mac app. I have a `QuickTime Movie View` that has a movie uploaded to it. When I press run, It doesn't work, the window doesn't show and my movie doesn't play!

Xcode tells me this:

`Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"`

How can I get my movie app to work?

I followed a youtube tutorial made on an older version of Xcode, so I don't know how to make it work on Xcode 4.2

This is the console code:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
[Switching to process 12270 thread 0x0]
2012-01-18 13:59:44.191 TestMovie[12270:707] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-01-18 13:59:44.192 TestMovie[12270:707] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (QTMovieView)
2012-01-18 13:59:44.194 TestMovie[12270:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ee9ed5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da0ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa7d9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2714
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aba4a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b682530 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 486
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a455679 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1051
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a546cac -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 3998
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aba4a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6ab44b -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 519
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a357e2d -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 2099
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    20  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a3574d8 loadNib + 235
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356a28 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356943 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356886 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a5ca637 NSApplicationMain + 398
    26  TestMovie                           0x0000000100001792 main + 34
    27  TestMovie                           0x0000000100001764 start + 52
)
2012-01-18 13:59:44.240 TestMovie[12270:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (QTMovieView)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ee9ed5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da0ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b3da044 +[NSException raise:format:] + 116
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa7d9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2714
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aba4a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b682530 -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 486
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a455679 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 1051
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a546cac -[NSWindowTemplate initWithCoder:] + 3998
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aba4a -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 1193
    15  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6ab44b -[NSSet(NSSet) initWithCoder:] + 519
    16  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a357e2d -[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:] + 2099
    19  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6aa86b _decodeObjectBinary + 2860
    20  Foundation                          0x00007fff8b6a9b86 _decodeObject + 201
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a3574d8 loadNib + 235
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356a28 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 217
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356943 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 141
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a356886 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 364
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a5ca637 NSApplicationMain + 398
    26  TestMovie                           0x0000000100001792 main + 34
    27  TestMovie                           0x0000000100001764 start + 52
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you linking to QTKit? Interface Builder will let you add a `QTMovieView` even if your project doesn't reference `QTKit.framework`.

You need to link to QTKit in order to use QTMovieView. Xcode 4 moves the linked libraries list to a different location; see the Xcode documentation for where to find it